# How can I get colored folders back in Mavericks?

Tags: finder, macos

With the launch of the new tagging system in OS X Mavericks, the ability to color the actual folder line in the finder appears to be gone.

Is there anyway to bring this back??

Comment: I'm guessing this is a big no, but let's see before we call it for sure. The old labels hit you over the head with color in list view - the new design is extremely subtle to my eyes.

Comment: It was nice to be able to see quickly colored files, especially if the finder window was wide. Now the only color is on the far right, not very helpful if the pane is wide and have to track back to the left.

Comment: Especially not helpful if the column width spans past the edge of the Finder window.